# managing wpf windows from external object

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-mvc

I have an application with a part consisting in a set of wpf windows in loop, sending a business object to make the changes in the model. Something like this (not real code):

```
class Window1 {

    BusinessObject obj;

    public Window1 (BusinessObject obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    /*  Things showing obj info and modifying it. */

    public void on_Button_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs args){
        new Window2(obj).Show();
       this.close();
    }
}

 class Window2 {

    BusinessObject obj;

    public Window2 (BusinessObject obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    /*  Things showing obj info and modifying it. */

    public void on_Button_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs args){
        new Window3(obj).Show();
       this.close();
    }
}

class Window3 {

    BusinessObject obj;

    public Window3 (BusinessObject obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    /*  Things showing obj info and modifying it. */

    public void on_Button_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs args){
        if (!obj.Finished) {
            new Window1(obj).Show();
            this.close();
        }
    }
}
```

With new changes, instead of always being  W1 -> W2 -> W3 -> W1, depending on the info of the business object, there are 4 different paths for each iteration: W1 -> W2 -> W3 -> W2 -> W1, or W1 -> W2 -> W3 -> W1 -> W2 -> W1, so i would need to have something like an state for each window.

```
class Window1 {
    BusinessObject obj;

    public Window1 (BusinessObject obj, int path, int repetition){
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    /*  Things showing obj info and modifying it. */

    public void on_Button_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs args){
        if (path == 0) {
           new Window2(obj).Show();
           this.close();
        }
        if (path == 1 && repetition = 0){
            new Window2(obj, path, 0).Show();
            this.close();
        }
        else {
            new Window3(obj, path, 1).Show();
            this.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to instead of doing this to have a window manager controlling the windows? Like this

```
while (true) {
    new Window1(obj).Show();
    wait(Window1);
    new Window2(obj).Show();
    wait(Window2); 
     if (obj.Condition1){
        new Window3(obj).Show();
    } else {
        new Window1(obj).Show();
         wait(Window1);
         new Window3(obj).Show();
    }
}
```

If possible, would be a bad practice?

Comment: The WPF NavigationService should do the trick, good example here: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not quite clear to me that what you are trying to achieve actually makes a lot of sense, here goes a possible solution (assuming that you can configure the rules you need).

First we have a configurable "StateMachine", where you can couple the state of the business object to the next window that should be created.

```
public class StateMachine
{
    private readonly List<Tuple<Predicate<MyBusinessObject>, Func<MyBusinessObject, StateMachine, Window>>> _matchList;
    public StateMachine()
    {
        _matchList = new List<Tuple<Predicate<MyBusinessObject>, Func<MyBusinessObject, StateMachine, Window>>>();
    }

    public void RegisterState(Predicate<MyBusinessObject> predicate, Func<MyBusinessObject, StateMachine, Window> windowFactory)
    {
        _matchList.Add(Tuple.Create(predicate, windowFactory));
    }
    public Window Next(MyBusinessObject currentState)
    {
        var entry = _matchList.Where(m => m.Item1(currentState)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (entry != null)
            return entry.Item2(currentState, this);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Before you create the windows, at application initialization time, you create an instance of the state machine and configure your rules:

```
    public StateMachine InitializeStateMachine()
    {
        var stateMachine = new StateMachine();
        // If condition1 is true open Window2
        stateMachine.RegisterState(bo => bo.Condition1, (bo, sm) => new Window2(bo, sm));
        // If the sum is more than 12.5 and some value is not 42 open Window3
        stateMachine.RegisterState(bo => bo.SomeSum > 12.5 && bo.SomeValue != 42, (bo, sm) => new Window3(bo, sm));
        // The answer to life and everything will open Window4
        stateMachine.RegisterState(bo => bo.SomeValue == 42, (bo, sm) => new Window3(bo, sm));
        // More rules ...
        // If no other condition matches, open Window1
        stateMachine.RegisterState(bo => true, (bo, sm) => new Window1(bo, sm));
        return stateMachine;
    }
```

Your window classes all need to implement a constructor that takes the business object instance and the state machine instance. When needing to open a new window, they only need to call `Next` on the statemachine.

```
public class Window1 : Window
{
    private readonly StateMachine _stateMachine;
    private readonly MyBusinessObject _businessObject;

    public Window1(MyBusinessObject businessObject, StateMachine stateMachine)
    {
        _stateMachine = stateMachine;
        _businessObject = businessObject;
    }

    public void on_Button_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // look ma, no logic ...
        var nextWindow = _stateMachine.Next(_businessObject);
        if (nextWindow != null)
            nextWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

If the logic is more complicated, or does not depend only on the state of the business object itself, a few adaptations need to be made to take those into account.